# Product followed by another product: how to solve?

Tags: products

I want to verify the result that I found to this equation:

$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{2} ij$

I found that $\prod_{j=1}^{2} ij = 2i^2$. After that I did: $\prod_{i=1}^{n} 2i^2$ and, finally, found that:

$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{2} ij = 2^n (n!)^2$

I am not sure if I can solve it this way (a product first and then another product).

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what is expected.  You can imagine parentheses around the inner product.  You should evaluate that first, as you did.

Comment: Yep. Halfway through writing my answer I realised mine’s not correct.

Comment: @BenjaminWang:  but it was an easy fix.  You just make the $i$ into $i^2$ and you are there.